# Stripping useless elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, is-empty

I want to strip all elements within the DOM that contains useless spaces or are empty (I'm working with an outdated back-end system that generates some messy HTML and these elements can sometimes add unwanted spaces in the design). Using the filter function I'm able to test for specific cases but for some reason it doesn't seem to work with empty elements so I tried to test to see if any elements length is < 0 and then remove it. Why doesn't this work, and is there a way to do it with the filter function? I've tried

```
    ("&lt;br&gt;", "", "&nbsp;");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

```
stripEmpties();

function stripEmpties() {
    var domChildren = $("*").children();
    if (domChildren.length <= 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        domChildren.filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === ("&lt;br&gt;", "&nbsp;");
        }).remove();
    }
}
```

Actually after playing with it I now see that only the last match is even used in the filter so it looks like I can't use this list format I've come up with. So I guess another question would be is there a way to get similar functionality while checking multiple cases with the filter function?

Comment: I don't really see the need for this if done on the client side. First, you already wasted the bandwidth by sending the useless elements, and afterwards you spend additional resources on removing them, without it making any optical difference to the user? Why's that? If this should be done the right way, you have to remove them on the server side, before sending the document.

Comment: `innerHTML` of `<br>` is null or undefined or doesn't exists - dunno, but it's not `<br>`. Have a look at `tagName`, for example `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].tagName`

Comment: As I said, yes this SHOULD be taken care of on the server side but that's not an option for this set of projects it's a legacy system that a client owns and is phasing out but needs a quick dirty solution in the meantime. And actually I don't even really NEED to be able to remove empty elements in this particular case but after tinkering with it for a while I am just curious.

Comment: Try `$("<br>", "*:empty").remove()`. [Edit]: Oh, wait, that's not quite waht you'Re trying, right? This would remove all <br>s, but no elements that only contains them...

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as it sounds and it certainly is not efficient if the document is large. For example this will remove all br, img (tags with no innerHtml) etc tags aswell:

```
$(function () {
    $("*").filter(function () {
        return ($(this).text().trim() === "");
    }).remove();
});
```

So maybe you should use a better selector than "*", for example "div".